# Error while running ruby script/server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got an error while running ruby script/server,

DRb::DRbConnError in HomeController#index

druby://localhost:3333 - #

Iam not able to understand where is the exact error, is there any gem missing or server issue.

Comment: Please provide us with more information, add the source code and a full stacktrace. Try to reproduce your problem in an independent script (instead from within a rails controller).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the ruby app you are trying to start is supposed to do but it seems to use a  [DRB server](http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/drb/introduction.html), which you would have to start before.